# Comparing Free Monoids and Kleene Closures (Stars)

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid

These are going to be a straight-to-the-point questions:

What is the difference between a free monoid and a Kleene Closure (Star) when generated by the set $A=\{1\}$?

Let $A^*$ be the free monoid over $A$ and $A^+$ be the Kleene Closure over $A$. If we categorize the set $A$ and the two algebraic structures $A^*$ and $A^+$, we define two functors $F^*:A\to A^*$ and $F^+:A\to A^+$. Can either functor become the equivalence of categories (e.g.,  $F^*:A\cong A^*$ and $F^+:A\cong A^+$)?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "categorize the set $A$ and the two algebraic structures $A^*$ and $A^+$"?

Comment: @A.P. What I mean is let's turn $A,A^*, and A^+$ into categories.

Comment: How? This makes sense for a monoid (i.e. a category with a single object), but what do you do with a set?

Comment: @A.P. I actually forgot a whole section of the question. The set is ordered so the morphisms are preorders such that $x\to y$ iff $x\ll y$. Therefore making the morphisms of $A^*$ and $A^+$ ordered as well. My bad.

Comment: Here you say that $A$ is a singleton, so, as a category, it is a category with one object and one morphism?

Comment: @A.P. Yes. $1\to1$ iff $1\ll1$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33762/discussion-between-a-p-and-julian-rachman).

Comment: It may help to observe that the free monoid on a singleton is essentially the natural numbers under addition with unit being 0 ---we obtain this view by considering the length of an expression since its contents are all the singleton element and so are irrelevant since parenthesization also does not matter since monoid operations are associtive.

Answer (score 0):

Kleene closure describes the submonoid of a free monoid generated by a subset of it. I don't understand the second half of your question.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your first sentence of your response?

Comment: @Julian: I don't know what you want elaboration on. Can you be more specific? "Kleene closure" is an operation that takes as input a collection of words on some alphabet $X$ and returns as output the set of all words obtained from those words using concatenation (including the empty concatenation). You can interpret these words as elements of the free monoid on $X$, and then this construction outputs the submonoid generated by those words. But I already said this.